# How to align a value in center of a cell of a table?

Tags: html, css

I'm filling the cell with an svg line + an svg circle, and the circle is on top of the line. that works perfectly but their position isn't in center it's in top left.

```css
td {
   position: relative;
}
    
td svg {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
    
svg.circle { 
   top: 1px;
   left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <td height="20" width="20" align="center" valign="center" class="col3 row6">
        <svg class="circle" height="18" width="18">
            <circle cx="9" cy="9" r="6" fill="red"></circle>
        </svg>
        <svg class="line" height="20" width="20">
            <line x1="0" y1="9" x2="20" y2="9" style="stroke:red;stroke-width:5"></line>
        </svg>
    </td>
</table>
```

Even if I remove the CSS's part it stays at the top left, but when I remove `position: absolute` it fixes the problem but the circle isn't on top anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

td {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

td svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 0;
}

.circle {
  left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td height="20" width="20" align="center" valign="center" class="col3 row6">
    <svg class="circle" height="18" width="18">
        <circle cx="9" cy="9" r="6" fill="red"></circle>
    </svg>
    <svg class="line" height="20" width="20">
        <line x1="0" y1="9" x2="20" y2="9" style="stroke:red;stroke-width:5"></line>
    </svg>
  </td>
</table>
```

Comment: that didn't do it

Comment: you need the circle to be on the center of the line right?

Comment: on the center of the cell

Comment: where is the cell here?!

Comment: the <td> element

Comment: Oh got it! check the answer now and remove the border around `td` when you're clear enough.

Comment: hey I'm sorry about this, but you can see that it's not 100% in the center [here](https://ibb.co/pQGVdLX) is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211494/discussion-between-manjuboyz-and-moswers).

Answer (score -1):

Use should use `flexbox` in my opinion.

```
.cell-content{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

<table>
<div class='cell-content'>
<td height="20" width="20" align="center" valign="center" class="col3 row6">
    <svg class="circle" height="18" width="18">
        <circle cx="9" cy="9" r="6" fill="red"></circle>
    </svg>
    <svg class="line" height="20" width="20">
        <line x1="0" y1="9" x2="20" y2="9" style="stroke:red;stroke-width:5"></line>
    </svg>
</div>
</td>
</table>
```

Comment: I can't create a div element, bcuz I'm using js to create the table and I have then to rewrite the whole thing, I know that  there is a simpler way. thanks anyway